# Split view controller that is only sometimes split?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an iPad app that seems like a natural fit for using a Master / Detail UISplitViewController for portrait and companion detail controller / popover for navigation.

But...  I would sometimes like to use the full screen for the detail controller in portrait as well, turning the master into a popover here as well.

Is there any best practices or sample code explaining how this can be done?

Is a UISplitViewController the appropriate root view?

Any tips that focus on using iOS 5 and segues are especially appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this is possible under iOS 5.

Use the following function in your UISplitViewController delegate:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Return YES even in landscape view, and the SplitViewController will function with a popover-style interface just like in portrait.  If you want to revert back to the normal split view behavior, use this function to return NO in landscape.

Comment: How to enable it again? In iOS 5.1 this method is only called once at the beginning and then never again. Even not when the orientation changes.

Comment: @Chris : yes, i am also facing a same problem. You got any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Tarun: Yes, write your own SplitViewController and inherit from the existing one. Then you can control when it is displayed or not.